# Using pyspark in a python module

Tags: python, pyspark

Can I add functionality to my Python module to use pyspark? I have to parse very large data files in a non-trivial way.

If so, could anyone point me towards a resource? I'm a bit confused about this whole thing, because whenever I write a python script using pyspark, I have to run it with `spark-submit` etc., so I'm not sure how I'd set that up within a module. I'm also not sure how one would pass in the required/available resources on the system the module is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you want to start with a high-level understanding of [Spark's overall architecture](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html), which is to say, a Driver node (one special computer) controls a Cluster of Executor nodes (replaceable other computers, virtual or otherwise). When you run `spark-submit`, what is happening is that you are POSTing a program definition to the Driver. The Driver then turns this program into an Execution Plan, which is then used to tell the Executors how to move the data around to process your data.

What this means is that in general, you don't really embed Spark in your module. You think about a way to either make your module communicate with a Spark Cluster and/or the results of the Cluster's Jobs, OR, you think more about [loading your module into Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html).

> you need to make sure that your code and all used libraries are available on the executors.

For practical purposes usually this means that you write your code in python using pyspark libraries, package it as a wheel, and load it into the cluster. Then you can `spark-submit` your job definitions that make use of the module.

One newer feature that might be interesting to you is [Spark Connect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html) which actually lets your local machine/python interpreter connect directly to the Cluster

> using unresolved logical plans as a language-agnostic protocol between the client and the Spark driver.

This may be closer to what you're imagining is going on with Spark generally, but I'd recommend you familiarize yourself with the basics of the architecture before diving too deeply into the newer stuff.

Comment: I see. Thank you for all the info. I was thinking about this the wrong way.